# Bad quality question reviewers

Tags: discussion, new-users, review-queue, low-quality-posts

Is it possible to see who reviewed a question of someone who did a First Post?

Found a question in the queue, someone asking how to write code for something, I was surprised to see there were no first comments asking the person to post what they had attempted or referring to [ask], instead the first comment provided a line of code (which was basically the answer) with an up-vote.

I would have believed that the person who reviews the question would have flagged it and or asked the poster to review [ask] and at the very least to post some code...

I am asking this to know how the community deals with people who don't put an effort on reviewing other peoples posts?

[Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173089/i-need-to-print-the-fibonacci-series-in-a-single-line-using-apex-how-can-it-be) is an example post, however, it has been put [on hold] by the community. (thumbs up for that)

Comment: Care to link to the specific post you are asking about? It is possible to implement a review ban, although I don't believe one has ever been placed here.

Comment: just did, the question is now on hold =P

Comment: maybe the question wasn't reviewed until recently, but I am curious to know if it was reviewed before being put on hold. I am pretty sure there are other examples out there

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes if you're in a hurry, you can accidentally click the wrong button and then can't go back to change it later. That's always annoyed me about the review queue. I'm glad you noticed questions being closed without receiving any comments and brought it to the mods attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it was reviewed. The same person also decided no action was needed on an answer whose content was:

> hey this will add message in url not on page???

So...yeah it seems they deserve a review ban. When two of their three most recent reviews fall so blatantly outside community guidelines, it is time to take action.

Comment: Good to know, maybe a warning message to the reviewer would also be helpful, just so they are aware that they should put more effort .

Comment: I did also send a warning message. Thanks for the heads up and thanks for the reviewing effort you yourself have been putting in.

Comment: I assume there is a minimum rep or a moderator permission needed to be able to do this?

Comment: I believe you need [Access To Moderator Tools](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) to review reviews.